# How to use JQuery .find() properly when using multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page where users can create a newsitem. Each news item is displayed in a new div, with multiple divs inside to divide content into multiple columns, to hide some content etc. The following code is a stripped down version of 1 newsitem:

```
<div class="news-item clearfix" id="c-b504b780-06a8-49bc-ba04-84d1fbba1a94">

<h2>This is a title</h2>

<div class="news-image div-right">
    <a class="img-gallery" href="Images/Dynamic/700x700/NewsItem/44951/example.png" rel="lightbox-This is a title"><img class="img-responsive clear" src="Images/Dynamic/200x200c/NewsItem/44951/example.png" /></a><br />
</div>

<div class="preview one-image">
    <p>Text here</p>    
</div>

<div class="full div-hide">
    <p>Text here</p> <img src="Images/Dynamic/full/NewsItem/44951/example.png" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

As you can see, each newsitem has a generated code attached to it which is used to identify unique newsitems, the code is also used in my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {

    var newsdiv = $('#c-b504b780-06a8-49bc-ba04-84d1fbba1a94');
    $('#c-b504b780-06a8-49bc-ba04-84d1fbba1a94 > .full').find('img').wrap(function () { return "<a href='" + $(this).attr('src') + "'></a>"; });

})();
</script>
```

This script is supposed to put an anchor tag around the image found in my full div-hide class, however this is not working properly. I assume my jquery selector is not selecting the right div, but I do not know what it should be. Do you have an idea how I can wrap my anchor tags around images inside the class="full" div?

Comment: you are confusing an IIFE with document ready handler syntx `$(fn)`  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two issue in document ready function:

1) You have not added jquery selector(`$`) in front of ready function.

2) You dont need to call the document ready function.

```
  $(function () {
/*^^missing selector here*/ 

   var newsdiv = $('#c-b504b780-06a8-49bc-ba04-84d1fbba1a94');
   $('#c-b504b780-06a8-49bc-ba04-84d1fbba1a94 > .full').find('img').wrap(function () { return "<a href='" + $(this).attr('src') + "'></a>"; });

});
 /*^^ () not required here*/
```

and to make it work for all the divs:

```
$('.news-item .full img').each(function(){
  $(this).wrap("<a href='" + $(this).attr('src') + "'></a>");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ptqpz6f/)**

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much, been struggling with this for over 2 hours already, haha.

Comment: glad it helps kevin. :) You should check console for errors in such situations.

Comment: lol @MilindAnantwar nice one ! didn't see the mistake on doc ready :D +1 from me

Comment: Yea, I've never really understood working with the console, will look it up today to learn working and debugging with the console as well, as it seems to help a lot in these situations :-)

Comment: happens :) .we focus for issues in functionality code.. and some times we end up knowing that the basic syntax is screwed up.

Comment: @KevinVoorn your syntax was correct so no error in console in this case

Comment: @A.Wolff: agree.. he would not get it in console. http://jsfiddle.net/spd1cq36/ . only debugging would have helped him :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#c-b504b780-06a8-49bc-ba04-84d1fbba1a94 > .full img').each(function() {
   $(this).wrap(function () { return "<a href='" + $(this).attr('src') + "'></a>"; });
});
```

Comment: I tried to implement this, however it gives me the same effect as my example, the images are not getting wrapped inside an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.full').find('img').each(function() {
   // your code here ..
});
```